# Want to display Calculated Negative balance on Credit Side Column and Positive on Debit Side

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am creating Trail Balance Report in Oracle Apex.

I have table in the following format:

```
Account_id     Title    DC    Amount
    10         Test     1     3000
    10         Test     2     5000
    20         XYZ      1     7000
    20         XYZ      2     2000
```

DC Column = 1 Mean Debit and 2 Mean Credit

I want if sum amount is negative then show Net Credit Amount on Credit side column without Negative Sign. If sum amount is positive then show Net Debit Amount on Debit side column. Like

```
Account_id     Title    Debit    Credit
    10         Test              2000
    20         XYZ      5000
```

How to do it with Sql Query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the conditional aggregation.

```
select account_id, title,
       case when sum(case when DC = 1 then amount else -1*amount end) > 0 
            then sum(case when DC = 1 then amount else -1*amount end) 
       end debit,
       case when sum(case when DC = 2 then amount else -1*amount end) > 0 
            then sum(case when DC = 2 then amount else -1*amount end) 
       end credit
  from your_table t
 group by account_id, title
```

Comment: Thanks This work. Can you explain this logic? I can't understand how it works

Comment: I am just checking if debit amount is greater or credit amount. and based on that amount deciding which column to be used for displaying the difference.

Answer (score 0):

First I calculate the balance in the inline view, then I apply group by clause to get the desired output.

```sql
select ACCOUNT_ID, TITLE, case when BALANCE < 0 then abs(BALANCE) end Debit, case when BALANCE >= 0 then BALANCE end credit
from (
   select ACCOUNT_ID, TITLE, DC, AMOUNT
     , sum(case when DC = 1 then -1 * AMOUNT else AMOUNT end)over(partition by ACCOUNT_ID, 
            TITLE) balance
   from your_table
)
group by ACCOUNT_ID, TITLE, BALANCE
;
```